# Mongoose Schema "new" keyword

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When declaring a mongoose schema, I noticed that using

```
mongoose.Schema({});
```

and

```
new mongoose.Schema({});
```

work.

Is there any difference? Which way is better?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its the same thing. From the [source](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/3.8.x/lib/schema.js):

```
if (!(this instanceof Schema))
    return new Schema(obj, options);
```

If you omit `new`, it will just create an instance for you.