# Creating Mongoose Schemas with or without 'new' keyword?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Most of the examples I have seen online do something like...

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: String
});
```

However, recently I found a book do the above... but without the new keyword.

```
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    age: String
});
```

I am now confused. Do we use the new keyword for creating the schema or not.. and what happens in both cases?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose Schema "new" keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22596806/1048572)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Both are valid and returns a new instance of the `Mongoose.Schema` class. What this means is that both does exactly the same. This [line](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/f2a40b24d68a929d00108c74bde72ab960de5fd8/lib/schema.js#L69-L71) checks whether you already have an instance of the Schema class, if not, it returns one for you.

To summarize, if you call

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({})
```

you initialize an instance yourself, while if you call

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({})
```

mongoose initializes one for you, with this:

```
function Schema(obj, options) {
  if (!(this instanceof Schema)) {
    return new Schema(obj, options);
  }
  ...
```

Comment: @Grateful are you sure you understood everything? I want to make sure you understood what I meant. Have you worked with other object-oriented languages like PHP before? The reason I'm asking is because `mongoose.Schema` is a `Class`, which you have to initialize instances of to use, by using `new Class()`

Comment: I understand your answer. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad, happy coding fella!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree with the above answer. But here I would like to add some more important points to it. Looking at the [Mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#schema_Schema), I feel like it should always be called with the new keyword since Schema is a constructor.

Both will work and are valid, but my suggestion is to only use the `new mongoose.Schema()` since it's the correct way. Following standard conventions will make your code easier to read; not only for others but for you as well when you go back to it in 6 months.