# What is the difference between mongoose.Schema() and new mongoose.Schema()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

What is the difference between `mongoose.Schema()` and `new mongoose.Schema()`?

I used both the standards, and I think both do the same job. Does it affect in any way?

Comment: Are you sure that both do the same job? I dunno. Just asking too. It may be possible that they both do the same job. The `new` keyword there means `instantiate a new object` though

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719454/creating-mongoose-schemas-with-or-without-new-keyword

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating Mongoose Schemas with or without 'new' keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719454/creating-mongoose-schemas-with-or-without-new-keyword)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#schema_Schema), it should always be called with the `new` keyword, since `Schema` is a constructor.

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/schema.js#L94), it'll return a newly allocated object if you try to use it without the `new` keyword.

Both will work, but I would only use the first since it's the correct way.
Following standard conventions will make your code easier to read; not only for others, but for you as well when you go back to it in 6 months.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the standard practice and documentation, the only difference that i have figured out is this : (VS code specific)
VS code seems to recognise the model which are created using a schema(created using **new** ) . ie. MongoDB specific intellisense like query operations, CRUD methods seem to be working.

Note. Schemas created without **new** do work fine in all the cases but the CRUD related intellisense (at least for my case) do not work.
[Without **new**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIXPX.png)
[with **new**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkFcE.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).